# Get count of an item in a column when values in other column are equal to some value

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

```
for i in range(0,9):
    num = training_data[training_data[i]==row[i]&training_data[9]==1].groupby([i,9]).size()
    print num
    count_equals.append(num)
```

DataFrame

---

```
      0  1  2   3  4   5  6  7  8  9
```

---

```
314   1  1  1   1  1   1  2  1  1  1 
431   5  1  1   3  4   1  3  2  1  1
260  10  5  8  10  3  10  5  1  3 -1
91    3  1  1   2  2   1  1  1  1  1
337   1  1  1   1  2   1  3  1  1  1
```

I need counts into a list else groupby without second condition works.
if row =[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
then the count_equals list should be [2,4,4,2,4,1,3,4]

> Error: 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "naive.py", line 46, in 
>       num = training_data[training_data[i]==row[i]&training_data[9]==1].groupby([i,9]).size()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 917, in **nonzero**
>       .format(self.**class**.**name**))
>   ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 0):

In `training_data[i]==row[i]&training_data[9]==1`, the operator `&` has higher precedence than `==`. Surround the relational expressions with parentheses before doing the AND:

```
(training_data[i]==row[i]) & (training_data[9]==1)
```